# Can we build an app with React where we write single code and support all platform?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to build a simple app using React for all platforms i.e. Mobile, Windows OS, Mac OS and WebApp.
But I want to have a single codebase for all.
Can we build such app using React JS?

Comment: A webapp would run on all platforms but if requirement is native app and webapp with same code --> check out React native web - https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web

Comment: https://proton-native.js.org/#/

Comment: react-native time to shine! https://facebook.github.io/react-native/